# Fatal Error: "MATLAB_PREFDIR must be an absolute path. Cannot set preferences directory to the relative path.." occurs when spmd is used

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, fatal-error

I am running a program on **Matlab** and I use **spmd** to parallelize my code.

The same code runs on 2 different PCs. One of them runs perfectly well, but the other doesn't and the Fatal Error occurs.
If I try to run a non-parallelized program, there are no errors. I don't know if there is a problem with this specific command or if I did something wrong myself.

Could it be related to the directories in which I have saved my code files?
If so then why does the non-parallelized program run?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you still have this problem, but anyway...
The problem is with the path to preferences folder. So, you need to change it.
Mostly such error occurs if you don't have write access to this folder or its located in hidden folder.
To open the current path of the prefdir type winopen(prefdir) in matlab Command window. Then copy all files from this folder into new one (for instance C:\MATLABPreferences).
Now you need to change a path of the prefdif using .bat file with the following text:

```
fullfile (matlabroot, 'bin', 'matlab')
 set MATLAB_PREFDIR=<New preference folder location>
 "<MATLAB executable location>"
```

Example:

```
 fullfile (matlabroot, 'bin', 'matlab')
 set MATLAB_PREFDIR=C:\MATLABPreferences
 "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\matlab.exe"
```

Run it and enjoy parallel computing with matlab.

More detailed explanation you can find [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/93696-how-do-i-change-the-matlab-preferences-directory-location).

Answer (score 0):

I've had problems with this, and so far the internet was not really useful. After hours of Googling, [this](https://ngththien.wordpress.com/2010/08/18/how-do-i-change-the-matlab-preferences-directory-location-on-windows-xp/) turned out to be useful. You just need to add a new variable to your environmental variables (in case you are using Windows) named `MATLAB_PREFDIR` with the location of the preferred directory. 

For me, it is `C:\Users\Balázs\AppData\Roaming\MathWorks\MATLAB\R2014a`, but you can get if you type `prefdir` into matlab's command line.